# How to change root hint in bind9?

Tags: linux, dns, bind

I have a root server and I want my recursive server's use it as root hint. So I change some config files on them. Following are the files I have changed on root server and recursive server.

- db.root on root server

```
  1 ;
  2 ; BIND data file for custom root 
  3 ;
  4 $TTL    604800
  5 @       IN      SOA     . nistopo.hit. (
  6                               2         ; Serial
  7                          604800         ; Refresh
  8                           86400         ; Retry
  9                         2419200         ; Expire
 10                          604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
 11 ;
 12 @       IN      NS      ns.nistopo.hit.
 13 ns.nistopo.hit. IN      A       10.10.11.131
```

- named.conf.default-zones on root server:

```
// prime the server with knowledge of the root servers
  2 zone "." {
  3         type master;
  4         file "/etc/bind/db.root";
  5 };
  6 
  7 // be authoritative for the localhost forward and reverse zones, and for
  8 // broadcast zones as per RFC 1912
  9 
 10 zone "localhost" {
 11         type master;
 12         file "/etc/bind/db.local";
 13 };
```

- root.hints on recursive server

```
.       3600000      NS    ns.nistopo.hit.
ns.nistopo.hit.      3600000      A     10.10.11.131
```

- named.conf.default-zones on recursive server

```
zone "." {
        type hint;
        file "/etc/bind/root.hints";
};

// be authoritative for the localhost forward and reverse zones, and for
// broadcast zones as per RFC 1912

zone "localhost" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.local";
};
```

Next is `dig` on recursive server:
[image]

However, there is no error in named log but it looks like zone '.' did not be loaded:
[image]

What's wrong with it?

Comment: I have no idea on how you can tweak the root file. I suppose you are not looking to access the Internet from those computers? That being said, to debug, I would use much small timeouts (i.e. instead of 86400, use maybe 60, i.e. 1 min. instead of 1 day) Otherwise the answers get cached in various places and it can be difficult to debug (in your case, though, you can always reboot since your computers will be 100% responsible for the caches).

Comment: The problem was caused by another zone 'hit' which I wrote in named.conf.  And you are right that I should use small timeouts when test. Cache is a trouble in bind9 when test for something.@AlexisWilke